# How to find sites which have embedded a particular RSS feed?

Tags: rss

One of our sites provides news for a niche industry. Historically, a news summary was syndicated to a number of external, third-part sites via several RSS feeds.

How can I identify which (if any) external sites embed one of our RSS feeds?

I've reviewed our access logs which shows numerous requests for our feeds, but I haven't been able to match these to any particular domain name.

Comment: _but I haven't been able to match these to any particular domain name_ - why? IP to domain doesn't work anymore? `inurl:rss` should work too

Comment: The IP address is the client who made the request, not the server where the feed is embedded. I have been able to find a few sites using `inurl`, `intext` and similar search operators, thanks.